# MYSQL from the 20th row to the last row

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, limit

Is there a way to say from the 20th row to the last row? Instead of saying 9999999999, I would like to replace it with something like the last row. Is that possible?

```
SELECT name from names limit 20, 9999999999
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, mysql still requires a `limit` when using an `offset`.

Comment: manual suggests just what you are doing "To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter.  "

Comment: Technically, your query is starting at the 21st row.

Comment: You can replace 999999 with a count query :P

Comment: @seahorsepip no you cant.

Comment: I meant: run the count query and then run the actual query with limit afterwards. Though It will probbaly only make it slower

Comment: @seahorsepip Then why suggest it?

Comment: Since I'm not totally sure, maybe someone has done benchmarks on it or some logical explanation why the method is slower of faster.